# A Diff.Equ. Similar to Bernoulli's Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was wondering if anyone would know how to solve the following:

$\dot{y}(t)=-y(t)+\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}+y(t)}$

That $\sqrt{2}$ is the only thing holding me back (any denominator displacement for that matter), otherwise it'd be Bernoulli's Equation.

Comment: **Hint:** It is a Separable Equation, so separate, integrate and simplify.

Comment: I agree, but it's the simplification that's stalling things. Doing this gives me a nasty log times a hyper arctan. Using @player100's suggestion provides something cleaner, but I get stuck at the following:
$\left(y-b_1\right){}^{c_1} \left(\frac{b_1 \left(1-c_1\right)+\sqrt{2}}{c_1}+y\right){}^{1-c_1}=\exp{-t}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=\sqrt{2}$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{2-y(a+y)}{a+y}$$
$$\frac{a+y}{2-ay-y^2}dy=dt$$
Factor the denominator, such that $(y-b_1)(y-b_2)=y^2+ay-2$, then find coefficients $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $c_1(y-b_2)+c_2(y-b_1)=a+y$. This turns out to be a system where $c_1+c_2=1$ and $c_1 b_2+c_2 b_1 = -a$

Then solve,
$$\frac{c_1dy}{y-b_1}+\frac{c_2dy}{y-b_2}=-dt$$